# Embedded youtube clicps - play next?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have few youtube clips embedded on page. Is it possible to play second clip after first finishes?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are the videos positioned separately on the page, or do want a single video pane that cycles through the videos?

Comment: I want several clips separately. I want tracklist from album shown as youtube clips in few embeds.